# How to choose the definitions in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

[image]

In PhpStorm 2020.1. There are multiple declarations of `\Spider`.

The default declaration is the first declaration. How to change the default  declaration?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there's no such feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17646

The only way you can affect resolution is by excluding the folder that has unnecessary declarations from indexing (`Settings/Preferences | Directories`), or by marking the files that has those declaration as text ones.